# Boolean intersect not working properly

Tags: boolean-modifier

I'm following along in a BlenderGuru tutorial and have come across the part where you enlarge the base mesh of the house to chop off the excess clapboard sidings in nonessential areas. Though, when I scale the base house mesh along the normals it ends up not placing the sidings properly. Any advice?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1aNnERnHRZg
(issue at 2:20)

[image]

[image]

Comment: did u try to apply scale + rotation before?

Comment: Yes I did @Chris

Comment: ok, pls add link of the tutorial + exact time in your question and add blend file so we can check it out. thx.

Comment: @Chris Updated with blend file and Video. Thank you so much!